PHP 8.1+ docker containers give NO_PUBKEY errors when doing apt-get update
Consider this Dockerfile:
FROM php:8.0-apache

RUN apt-get update

If I build that with sudo docker build -t test . it works great. But if I change php:8.0-apache to php:8.1-apache and try to build using the same command I start getting a bunch of NO_PUBKEY errors:
    Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease
      The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0E98404D386FA1D9 NO_PUBKEY 6ED0E7B82643E131 NO_PUBKEY F8D2585B8783D481
    Err:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease
      The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0E98404D386FA1D9 NO_PUBKEY 6ED0E7B82643E131
    Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease
      The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 54404762BBB6E853 NO_PUBKEY BDE6D2B9216EC7A8
    Reading package lists...
    W: GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0E98404D386FA1D9 NO_PUBKEY 6ED0E7B82643E131 NO_PUBKEY F8D2585B8783D481
    E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease' is not signed.
    W: GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0E98404D386FA1D9 NO_PUBKEY 6ED0E7B82643E131
    E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease' is not signed.
    W: GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 54404762BBB6E853 NO_PUBKEY BDE6D2B9216EC7A8
    E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease' is not signed.
    E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke 'rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true'
    E: Sub-process returned an error code
    The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update' returned a non-zero code: 100

If I remove the RUN apt-get update bit, build the Dockerfile, do sudo docker run -i -t --privileged test bash to get into the container and then do apt-get update it works but not without the --privileged bit. The problem is that --privileged doesn't appear to be an option for docker build so if that's required than does that mean I can't ever build a container with apt-get update for PHP 8.1+?
And what changed from the PHP 8.0 Docker images to the PHP 8.1 ones to make this a thing?

How is this problem related to PHP? Why do you need to run apt-get update? Did you report this as a bug to the maintainers of that base image?

Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77256696/docker-with-php-8-2-raised-error-the-public-key-is-not-available

More infos at https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/1446

I had to update libseccomp. I was already at the newest version from my distro so I compiled it by downloading https://github.com/seccomp/libseccomp/releases/download/v2.5.5/libseccomp-2.5.5.tar.gz and then compiling it. I then reran sudo docker build -t test . and that worked!
I guess the issue is that newer base images were compiled with newer libc versions and thus there are newer kernel system calls that they're trying to use. Docker accounts for these with updated seccomp profiles but that only works if libseccomp knows about the newer syscalls.
edit: https://github.com/docker-library/official-images/issues/16829 (posted on May 23, 2024) talks about Docker and libseccomp in more detail.
